# Aircrack offline installation

Tags: deb, offline

I'm new to Ubuntu. And I was trying to hack my android hotspot with a wpa2-psk security. I tried to install aircrack manually by the `.deb` file but that didn't work.
 It gave me an error when I used the `dpkg` command.

My computer is completely offline so I tried to tether my connection of my phone to my computer and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install macchanger

sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng

sudo apt-get install reaver
```

but it said "Unable to locate package."

Comment: With a connection through your phone, try running `sudo apt update` and then try those commands again

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` first?

Comment: yup! that gave me an error too.

Comment: @BenJunior - Might be helpful to post that error as well...

Comment: What was the error that `dpkg` gave you when you tried to install aircrack through the `.deb` file? Posting all of the errors really helps in resolving your issue.

Comment: Wait. are you guys asking if I did this: `    sudo apt-get update    ` without the package name? if so then no. I didn't run that command. I did this: `    sudo apt-get update macchanger.   ` and the same for the others.

Comment: You should be able to update first before any package installation. Updating is the way apt downloads repositories indexes of packages. If you don't have any index, no package can be found. Alternatively, you can grab .deb packages from some repository and install it with `dpkg` command

Comment: **dpkg error:** 

`

    error processing aircrack.deb (- - install):
        cannot access archive: No such file or directory
    Errors were encountered while processing:
        aircrack.deb

`

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-get update` first.

After updating indexes, you can run all the commands to install packages:

`sudo apt-get install macchanger`

`sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng`

`sudo apt-get install reaver`